# Slick Slider - Slider Syncing - Scroll thumbnails without changing the main content?

Tags: slick.js

Im using Slick Slider and the Slider Syncing option. Is it possible to scroll the "thumbnails" (.slider-nav in the example) without changing the main image (.slider-for in the example)?

I only want the main image to change when you click on a thumbnail. This way you can scroll through all the thumbnails and when click on the one that you want.

http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is no option for this on the slick slider docs but there is jsfiddle example that works for me:

```
- http://jsfiddle.net/Virtual/webyrb9d/
```